# How to view vertices on model when not showing

Tags: blender

I have the model from the bellow image and when I'm entering Edit mode, I can't see any vertices. How can I enable them? I want to remove some parts of it. If I add a simple cube, on that I can see them. All the tutorials I've seen start with them on and tell you how to move/delete, and none of them talk about the situation when they aren't showing. Does it have something to do with the model and it can't be changed?

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q73V3.png)

This is the wireframe view:

[Wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqRMJ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://blender.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone told me the solution on another website:
"You've selected the armature, not the character object, if you want to edit the character, switch back to Object mode, select the character, switch to Edit mode, then choose the Vertex Select mode, press Alt Z if you want transparency."

Answer (score 0):

For me on Version 3.3 I could see the edges but not the vertices, because I needed to change the select mode from "edge select" to "vertex select" - tiny little buttons showing in edit mode on top left, left of the "view" menu.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Simply:

1. Select Model & Press Tab go to enter in Edit Mode
2. Next to the Edit Mode Dropdown box (under the Edit Menu) there are 3 buttons:
   a) 1st: Vertex Selection (**Select This one)
   b) 2nd: Edge Select
   c) 3rd Face Select
   Once you click on the 1st button (Vertex Select) you should be able to see the small dots on the VerticesHope it helps?